# How to get event logs on Windows Active Directory Server for actions performed on user accounts

Tags: active-directory, samba

On a Windows Active Directory server, we can perform several actions on the accounts like add account, enable, disable, reset account, reset password etc.
Is there anyway that I can get an event log of any such actions that were performed on the accounts?
eg: If one of my computer/system say comp1 has an account listed on my AD server. If I log into my AD server and I do a "Reset Account" for my computer/system comp1 which is listed on there. Is this event logged anywhere so that if I search in the event log, I see that a "Reset Account" action was performed for comp1 ? How and where can I get those event logs ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you may have come to the incorrect site for that question... (It doesn't really relate to coding )

Comment: @Xilpex Just trying to find any possible help I can get. I need to fix a bug related to this asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging via group policy, below link will give you step by step details on activating this, at least I think it will be a good place to start.                https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servergeeks/2014/07/16/auditing-active-directory/

Comment: Thank you. That is useful. Actually, the issue is in a customer environment. So I am not sure whether they had enabled logging/audit logging. If they have not already done then in that case how can I find any events logged related to that.

Comment: I am not aware of a single store where you can browse historical data, but if you are looking for specifics on a computer object you can run in powershell -  Get-ADComputer -Identity <computer name> -Properties * | fl to see a list of properties like when the password was last set.